# Representation of chemical formulas as strings?

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

Is there a standard manner of representing chemical formulas as linear strings?

For example, $H_2O$ can be represented with the string `H2O`. Isotopes are usually specified with a number before the element. But this must be preceded by a space, or it can be get mixed with the number right before: `O4 13CH`, which is equivalent to $O_4{^{13}C}H$.

I'm just wondering if there is any set of accepted conventions when representing chemical formulas as linear strings.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, the [simplified molecular-input line-entry system (SMILES)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system) and the [IUPAC International Chemical Identifier (InChI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Chemical_Identifier) are two examples of "human-readable" string notations for chemical formulas your are looking for.